# $.post - trying to echo textbox value to div

Tags: php, jquery

I want after I type text in the textbox and click the button for that text to appear in the div above the form but I keep getting a php error `undefined index: chattext`

HTML:

```
<div class="chatdiv"></div>

<form id="chatform" action="chat.php" method="post">
<textarea name="chattext"></textarea>
<button>Send</button>
</form>
```

CHAT.PHP

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['chattext'];
?>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {

    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        $.post('chat.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $('.chatdiv').html(data); 
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

}); // end ready
```

Comment: If you do a print_r($_POST) in your php file you can see exactly what was posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are serializing the `button`:

```
$(this).serialize()
```

not the form. Change it to:

```
$("#chatform").serialize()
```

For future reference, when you're getting little issues like this, take a look at your web browsers developers tool, under network. It will show you what data is being posted to the web server.

Comment: +1 For tip about using the console. So many don't know about this.

Answer (score 2):

You're not referencing the form in `serialize()`, the line should be:

`$('#chatform').serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the event listener to your form in order to use `$(this).serialize();`

```
$('form#chatform').on('submit', function(e) {
```